# What is the easiest way to reset a configuration file that I accidentally deleted?

Tags: package-management, pptpd

I have accidentally deleted a configuration file (`/etc/pptpd.conf`) and was wondering what would be the best way to recover the default configuration file that comes with the pptpd package. Is there a way to "checkout" a single file from a package?

Comment: The best way is a backup. Even better is to use a tool like `etckeeper` to keep your whole `/etc` folder under version control, which makes it easy to back out from a change (or accidental deletion) and which allows you to track down configuration changes that created problems.

Answer (score 4):

> *Is there a way to "checkout" a single file from a package?*

Yes, it's easy with the `dpkg-deb` tool.

1. Use `dpkg --list | grep pptpd` to find your *pptpd* version.
2. Download the appropriate deb file from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pptpd/
3. For convenience in this example, we'll assume the name is `pptpd.deb`

   - Use the following to get a TAR file of the contents from which you can extract the files you need:

     ```
     dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile pptpd.deb > pptpd.tar
     ```
4. You can mount the TAR in Nautilus to easily get to the file, or you can use command-line `tar`.
5. Alternatively, instead  of converting to a TAR file, you can directly extract the deb to a directory with:

   ```
   mkdir pptpd-temp && dpkg-deb -x pptpd.deb pptpd-temp
   ```

> Note: in this case, `pptpd.conf` is the default configuration file which comes with the package and is not created dynamically at install time, as `dpkg-deb` with the list switch `-c` demonstrates:
>
> ```
> $ dpkg-deb -c pptpd_1.3.4-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb | grep conf
>   -rw-r--r-- root/root      2247 2012-03-01 22:03 ./etc/pptpd.conf
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure packageName
```

In your case:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure pptpd
```

Comment: This doesn't always work, especially in this case, giving the error `Starting PPTP Daemon: /etc/pptpd.conf: No such file or directory
pptpd.`

Comment: but this command can execute the scripts that are part of the package

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't help if he deleted the *files* that came with the package :) `reconfigure` isn't going to find the deb and extract those files for him.

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest way is to run in terminal, one line at a time:

```
sudo apt-get purge pptpd
sudo apt-get install pptpd
```

This purges the install of `pptpd` (including configuration files) and then the second line re-installs.

Answer (score 0):

Another option for getting the files back, which is a bit less drastic than a remove/purge:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ppptd
```

That will re-download the package and should restore any missing files.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.